# Rolling a die, probability problem

Tags: probability

So this is a problem I'm stuck on,

You roll a fair 4-sided dice and with probability 1/3 you get to roll once more, and with probability 2/3 you have to stop. Assume that you get as many coins as the sum of the rolls. What is the probability you will win an even number of coins?

Can somebody help?

PS: You can get as many extra rolls as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}+\cdots=\frac{2}{9}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}9^{-n}=\frac{2}{9}\times\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}=\frac{2}{9}\times\frac{9}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$

$P(RS \; or\;  RRRS \; or\; ......)=P(RS)+P(RRRS)+...$

This because the events are disjoint. Secondly they are independent so that for instance: $P\left(RRRS\right)=P\left(R\right)\times P\left(R\right)\times P\left(R\right)\times P\left(S\right)$